# how to parse response string with different data in swift 5

Tags: ios, string, parsing, struct, swift5

I need to parse below sample strings to get status and code and bind it to a struct "ErrorData".

String1 - `("{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"status\" : \"400\",\n    \"code\" : \"INVALID_DATA\"\n  } ]\n}")`

String2 - `"{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"status\" : \"404\",\n    \"code\" : \"INVALID_AUTH\"\n  } ]\n}")`

```
public struct ErrorData  {
    var errorStatus: String?
    var errorCode: String?
}
```

These are only 2 samples string, there will be many more strings of same format with different status and code  value.
How do I parse above string with format as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

This is JSON. These structs match the data

```
struct ErrorData : Decodable {
    let errors : [ErrorItem]
}

struct ErrorItem : Decodable {
    let status, code : String
}
```

Parse it with

```
let jsonString = """
{"errors":[{"status":"400","code":"INVALID_DATA"}]}
"""

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorData.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    for item in result.errors {
        print(item.status, item.code)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```